# Configuring what commands xfce4-session-logout runs

Tags: xfce, session, suspend

The suspend command run when selecting ‘suspend’ from xfce4-session-logout does not work on my machine. I need it to run `s2ram -f -a 1`.

Where do I change what is being run to suspend the system?